# How to implement the same trait in multiple files/mods avoiding "conflicting implementations of trait" error?

Tags: rust

In Golang I can define an interface like this:

```golang
type DBRepo interface {
  PlayerByID(id uint64) (*domain.Player, error)
  TeamByID(id uint64) (*domain.Team, error)
  // many others
```

and I can implement them like this using different files:

```golang
// file: real_db.go
type RealDB struct {
  db *realDB
}

// file: player.go
func (r RealDB) PlayerByID(id uint64) (*domain.Player, error) {
  return r.db... // get from DB
}

// file: team.go
func (r RealDB) TeamByID(id uint64) (*domain.Team, error) {
  return r.db... // get from DB
}

// many others (files and methods)
```

I cannot undestand how to do the same in Rust:

```rust
#[async_trait::async_trait]
pub trait DBRepo: Send + Sync {
    async fn player_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()>;
    async fn team_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()>;
}
```

but if I write the below code in different files (and different mods too):

```rust
// file: player.rs
#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl DBRepo for Repo {
    async fn player_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(()) // get from DB
    }
}

// file: team.rs
#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl DBRepo for Repo {
    async fn team_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(()) // get from DB
    }
}
```

I get from the compiler:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `DBRepo` for type `Repo`
--> src\team.rs:22:1
   |
22 | impl DBRepo for Repo {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `Repo`
   |
  ::: src\player.rs:22:1
   |
22 | impl DBRepo for Repo {
   | ----------------------------------- first implementation here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
```

How can I fix this?

**I need to use all the methods on trait DBRepo**, I cannot split it in many traits.

Answer (score 1):

You could split up your DBRepo trait into multiple traits and define the DBRepo trait to require all the other traits.

```rust
#[async_trait::async_trait]
pub trait DBRepoPlayer: Send + Sync {
    async fn player_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()>;
}
#[async_trait::async_trait]
pub trait DBRepoTeam: Send + Sync {
    async fn team_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()>;
}
pub trait DBRepo: DBRepoPlayer + DBRepoTeam {}
impl<T: DBRepoPlayer + DBRepoTeam> DBRepo for T {}
```

then you implement the sub traits on the types:

```rust
// file: player.rs
#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl DBRepoPlayer for Repo {
    async fn player_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(()) // get from DB
    }
}

// file: team.rs
#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl DBRepoTeam for Repo {
    async fn team_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(()) // get from DB
    }
}
```

I know you said not to split up the trait but implementing the same trait for the same type multiple times is not possible in rust, neither is partial trait implementation.

Comment: I create a repl with your suggestion: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3de2b4c47502b5e3fbde48fdbc0dc162. But I read about https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait that is a way to not use new (dummy) traits. Can you help me?

Comment: Afaik there would be if all of the required traits were auto traits. But since they aren't even the compiler will tell you to create a new trait that requires all the others.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partially implement a trait in rust. If you have some type `Repo` and want to implement `DBRepo` for that type, the entire trait implementation must be defined in the `impl` block.

For example, this example will fail even if you don't split it across files:

```rust
struct A;

trait Foo {
    fn fn_1();
    fn fn_2();
}

impl Foo for A {
    fn fn_1() {}
}

impl Foo for A {
    fn fn_2() {}
}
```

This fails with the error "conflicting implementation for `A`" as you are seeing in your example with multiple files. Even in the same file, this does not work.

If you just do:

```rust
struct A;

trait Foo {
    fn fn_1();
    fn fn_2();
}

impl Foo for A {
    fn fn_1() {}
}
```

you will see you also get a compiler error: 'missing `fn_2` in implementation".

Without splitting the trait into multiple traits, the only way to implement this is include the entire trait impl in one file:

```rust
#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl DBRepo for Repo {
    async fn player_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(()) // get from DB
    }

    async fn team_by_id(&self, id: i64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(()) // get from DB
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no "How to fix" in this answer, right?

Comment: I will edit my answer to include how to fix, the implication is that the way to fix this is you have to implement the trait in one file. With your constraint that you don't want to split up the trait as the other user suggested, it's not possible to implement as-is in rust unfortunately